# Tires resonant humming at specific speed

Tags: tires, noise

Update 2:

- I checked the tire pressure, it was indeed too high (reduced from about 2.7 to 2.3)
- After doing this the noise was somewhat less (though still very significant, it is slightly less bothersome)
- Also the speed at which the problem occurs shifted and got slightly narrower (old range of 98-102 roughly becomes 97-100 now).

At this stage I am starting to believe this may simply be inherent to the tires. Will keep it open a bit more to hear whether there is anything else worth trying, but otherwise can accept the comment on tire pressure as an answer.

---

Update 1:

- The tires are brand new (by now perhaps 200km on them but it started right away). I don't think there is any sign of damage or wear.
- I cannot try 100km/h on any surface, but I tried it on multiple kinds of highways and it occurred everywhere, and on several of these roads the sound never happened at any speed with my previous tires/cars.
- The main question is: What are the likely root causes. (If the garage tells me it's not their fault I foresee another bill in my future, just wondered how realistic this is).

---

I recently started hearing humming sounds when I drive exactly 100 km/h. At this speed it happens every time. If I deviate more then 2km/h it is completely gone. I tested different gear or neutral and this has no impact.

So far it sounds much like [Resonant humming noise at 118km/h](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/43094/resonant-humming-noise-at-118km-h)

However, the difference is that I recently switched the tires and it happened directly after that. So I'm quite confident that the swap is the reason. The tires are new, same size as before (different brand) and on the bill it says alignment and balancing was performed.

This is the first time I used the garage so I am not sure what to think. I will call them but am looking for what to expect.

Comment: Are the tyres over-inflated?

Comment: On every surface or only one?

Comment: Picture of tire tread?

Comment: Some years ago the UK did some experiments with concrete road surfaces instead of asphalt on a few sections of motorway, and this type of tire noise was one of the unintended consequences. It tended to occur at a wider range of speeds, though.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many kms on the tires versus their rated life expectancy?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: Updated the question to address the comments of @SolarMike and some others.

Comment: And did you check the pressures? As that was clearly asked.

Comment: @HandyHowie They were indeed, updated the question. Curious if there is more, otherwise consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: I've had this with new tyres when they weren't balanced properly.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I got my tyres replaced and just after the replacement when i drove my car on motorway it gave me a resonating sound that came only at a speed of 100-110 km/h. So anyone has any idea about it?